# @Query JpaRepository, querying decimal(19,4) becomes null when mapped to DTO BigDecimal or Long

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

Sorry, this is my first time posting so forgive me for my formatting and details:

I am having trouble with a @Query via JpaRepository

```
    @Repository
public interface MonthlyBillingFeesRepository extends JpaRepository<MonthlyBillingFeesEntity, String> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.moo.operations.backend.dto.MonthlyAggregatedBillingFeesDto(" +
            "SUM(m.customMooTotalBillingFeesSummary698721), " +
            "m.entryDate) " +
            "FROM " +
            "MonthlyBillingFeesEntity m GROUP BY m.entryDate")
    public List<MonthlyAggregatedBillingFeesDto> getAllBillingFeesByMonth();
```

the DTO:

```
    public class MonthlyAggregatedBillingFeesDto {
        private Long customMooTotalBillingFeesSummary698721;
        @Type(type="timestamp")
        private Date entryDate;
    
        public MonthlyAggregatedBillingFeesDto(Long customMooTotalBillingFeesSummary698721, Date entryDate) {
            this.customMooTotalBillingFeesSummary698721 = customMooTotalBillingFeesSummary698721;
            this.entryDate = entryDate;

//getters setters
```

It works without a problem when I put the query directly into SQL. Also when I query via postman, it does return the entry dates properly, just not the Decimal values. I am not sure where the breakdown is. I have tried to use nativeQuery as well, and nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thank you all, so I actually figured it out. Basically my column names that started with underscore _ really was causing issues with the hibernate naming strategy. No matter what I did, it wouldn't query the right column name. I had to change the names of the columns to camelcase and used:

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

in the applications.properties file.